# How to getting <tags> name in XML

Tags: xml, cakephp

i'm beginner in cakephp,i don't know how to get the tags name in xml

```
<channel>
        <title>....</title>
        <link>.... </link>
</channel>
```

Comment: Is it the tag name you want to parse or data inside it?

Comment: Then you want the data inside and its about RSS (came to know from a comment on other answer). Why not use Simplepie. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the xml in array format and get the names, like:

```
$Xml = new Xml($rawXML);
$xmlAsArray = $Xml->toArray();

//OR by doing
$file = file_get_contents($your_RSS_file_url); 
$parsed_xml =& new XML($file); 
$parsed_xml = Set::reverse($parsed_xml); // will have data in array format
```

Hope it helps

Comment: hisudhir, i got Fatal error: Class 'XML' not found in.....                                                             here i want to pass the RSS Url instead of  my_xml_file.xml

Comment: see edited code above ... you could use file_get_contents for getting contents from RSS url and parse the xml

Comment: have you included XMLHelper in your controller